# are asp.net mvc actions are single user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I am trying to have a parallel functionality in my asp.net mvc 2 application. I have loaded a list of ip address in a table format in my view. And I want to see if they are pingable. So I fire up GetStatus(string ip) action on controller for every ip address with the help of jQuery.ajax(). I can see in firebug that all requests has been fired up. But on the server side in log4net logs I can see those requests are executed in sequential manner.

So I have 2 questions here

- Are asp.net mvc actions are single user? meaning what if one action is called by multiple users, will that particular action will execute one-by-one for each user and not on separate (magical) thread created by asp.net or IIS?
- What should be my approach to make it parallel, as ping is a network operation.

I work on asp.net but this aspect seems new to me. Any resources specific in this context are most welcome.

Edit: I am working on Asp.Net MVC 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you use sessions in your actions. Since sessions are not thread safe ASP.NET serializes access to them. So if you have 2 parallel requests for the same action from the same session (which is the case with AJAX requests) and if this action writes to the ASP.NET session, those 2 requests will be queued and executed sequentially.

If you disable the session in your web.config (`<sessionState mode="Off" />`) or you disable it for the given controller, requests will no longer be processed sequentially but in parallel. Of course this means that this controller should either not use the session at all or only use it for read-only. See the [`[SessionState]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    // actions in this controller can be processed in parallel
    // for requests from the same session
}
```

Comment: if asp.net serializes access to sessions, does it mean sessions are thread safe?

Comment: @Jun1st, no, it's exactly because sessions are **not thread safe** that ASP.NET locks the request and allows only one request for a given session at a time to execute. Remember this will happen only if you send 2 parallel requests for the same session. Two separate users (with separate sessions) sending parallel requests at the same time to the same action will be executed in parallel without any locking.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I am writing to session in Index action and  only doing read operation in GetStatus() action. But from SessionState attribute it looks, it can be used with only Class. What do you think should be the approach to achieve this parallelism with session access?

Comment: @Darin, we can say that requests are executed parallely. but once these parallel threads are accessing the same session, they'll face wait and lock situation.

Comment: @RamPatil, the only way is to split your actions into 2 separate controllers. The first one can have a read/write access to the session and the second controller will contain only an action with readonly access. In this case you could decorate it with the SessionState attribute and be able to trigger parallel AJAX requests to this action.

Comment: It's my bad. I have updated the question to state that I'm working on asp.net mvc2. And it seems SessionState is new in mvc3

Comment: @RamPatil, yes, it is available in ASP.NET MVC 3 only. For ASP.NET MVC 2, you may take a look at the following article: http://blog.whiletrue.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-sessions-and-concurrent-requests-not-what-youd-expect/ which uses MvcFutures.

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not single user. asp.net webform/mvc will create a new thread to handle a new request. two different requests at the same time will have two threads.

log4net will buffer any log requests, and flush all at one time. you simply cannot write two sentence at one line.

Comment: not sure about log4net buffering, but each statement will have correct timestamp. From the timestamp I can say that the action is getting executed sequentially. What @Darin says, that make more sense to me.