# ASP.NET MVC Multi-Threading, is it worth it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I'm a bit confused, my ASP.NET MVC app will be hosted on a server, so is there any point in making it multi-threaded? For example, if I want one thread to execute my translations, is this a good idea? Can someone elaborate this to me please? I'm a bit confused with web apps multi-threading versus desktop apps multi-threading.

Comment: I think that lot of tasks you would execute asynchronously on web will be replaced with AJAX calls to web methods, all depends on design

Comment: yeah actually i use AngularJS, on the client side, but the backend and the MVC code, thats my worry.

Comment: @user3455363 but those AJAX calls are going to be handled by a webserver, so that changes nothing.

Comment: yeah but on the client PC not server? or mI wrong?

Comment: Both; it involves client code hitting server code and then dealing with the response. They can certainly make for lighter use of the server in many cases, but the server is still sending the response to the AJAX call.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a few things to this.

The first is that every ASP.NET application (MVC or otherwise) is inherently multi-threaded: Each request will be processed on a separate thread, so you are automatically in a multi-threading situation and must consider this with any shared access to data (e.g. statics, etc.).

Another is that with MVC its particularly easy to write asynchronous controller methods like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int id)
{
  var model = await SomeMethodThatGetsModelAsync(id);
  return View(model);
}
```

Now, if we're already multi-threaded then why bother? The benefit is (ironically in a way) to use fewer threads. Assuming that `SomeMethodThatGetsModel(id)` may block or otherwise hold up the thread, `await`ing on `SomeMethodThatGetsModelAsync(id)` allows the current thread to handle another request. One of the limits on how many requests a webserver can handle is how many threads it can have handling those requests. Free up threads and you increase your throughput.

A further is that you may want some operation to happen in the background of the application as a whole, here the reason is the same as with desktop applications.

Simpilarly, if you have work that can be done simultaneously and which blocks (e.g. hit a database and two webservices) then your reason for doing so in a multi-threaded manner is the same as with a desktop app.

(In the last two cases though, be wary of using the default static thread pool, such as through `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `Task.Run`. Because this same thread pool is used for the main ASP.NET threads if you hit it heavily you're eating from the same plate as your framework. A few such uses is absolutely fine, but if you're making heavy use of separate threads then use a separate set of threads for them, perhaps with your own pooling mechanism).

Comment: Nice, thank you this clarifies some things in my head, just one more question, Threads are used when someone accesses my App/site ? when a new user is using it he gets a separate thread or seperate process? or do you have some literature on this, because i think i need to read it up a bit server requests and threading, im a bit paranoid about DDOS :D

Comment: A thread is used for every single hit, whether it's for an ASP.NET page or a static file there's a thread handling it on the server. (Not all of those threads will involve .NET threads and their particular overhead). When the response (again, ASP.NET or anything else) is sent the thread is free to handle another request, and further as above if we use `await` (and a few other possible approaches) a thread can pause handling one request that switch to another one, so this sort of asynchronous use increases how hard it is to DOS you, though it certainly is no miracle cure there.

Comment: Stupid question incoming: Should all of the controller methods generated by VS for ASP.NET MVC projects be converted to this type?

Comment: @Sinjai, only if it calls into something where what is called into has an async version (database operations, file operations, calling a webservice, to name the most common cases), so you've something to `await`. Otherwise you just get the overhead of the `Task` without any benefit.

Comment: @JonHanna Most of the generated CRUD methods have a `db.SaveChanges()` call. Why aren't they generated as async Tasks?

Comment: @Sinjai I'm not familiar with the design of the generator, I'm afraid, so I can't even make an educate guess as to what might be the reason.

Comment: I know this is asking a lot, but I can't find any good resources and I'm not sure it warrants a standalone question. Can you take a quick look at [what is generated](https://hastebin.com/uquvupunup.cs) or link me to a resource that might provide insight? I'm not sure why they would generate synchronous methods.

Comment: Hey maybe this is worth an edit, I got confused with your statement that "Each request will be processed on a separate thread" because I found myself putting the Thread to sleep and my whole app waiting for it to finish before handling ajax requests that were made to other controllers. I found the response in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896122/are-asp-net-mvc-actions-are-single-user

Answer (score 1):

> is there a point to make it Multi-Threaded?

that's won't work. The question is: does your application needs multi-threading? For example, if you receive a collection of big entities, that need to be preprocessed somehow before further actions, you might process each of them in separate thread instead of cycle.

> Im a bit confused with web apps multi threading vs desktop apps multi threading

Multithreading in asp.net and desktop are the same thing and works the same way.

Comment: nice, thanks for the answer, The only thing my app is doing is getting GET and POST request for my translations and user login / logout.. however that will be handled in AJAX/AngularJS as well