# Return multiple Lists using Multithreading in Json Format - C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

I'm new to threading that's why can't understand previous similar questions.
I want to return multiple lists from a JsonResult Method (don't know how can I do it).
I've a list method which will return lists according to the name provided:-

```
public JsonResult FetchTblData(AdminBundle abundleList)
{
    AdminBundle abundle = new AdminBundle();
    string innerMesage = string.Empty;
    if (Session["AdminBundle"] != null)
        abundle = (AdminBundle)Session["AdminBundle"];

    //abundle.ListType = Request.Form["TblList"].ToString();
    abundle.ListType = abundleList.ListType;

    if (abundleList.ListType != string.Empty)
    {
        using (SMContext db = new SMContext())
        {
            switch (abundleList.ListType)
            {
                case "Category":
                    List<Category> CategoryList = null;
                    CategoryList = db.CatObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList();
                    return new JsonResult { Data = CategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                //Class Starts
                case "Board":
                    List<Board> BoardList = null;
                    BoardList = db.BoardObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList();
                    return new JsonResult { Data = BoardList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
               default:
                    return new JsonResult { Data = innerMesage, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                    //Main default Ends
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = innerMesage, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this method from a different method and get returned lists here. But I don't know what and how to do this.

```
public JsonResult GetMultipleTblResult(AdminBundle aBundleFetch)
{
    if (aBundleFetch.TblName.Equals(Constants.Board))
    {
        aBundleFetch.TblName = Constants.Board;
        Thread objBoard = new Thread(FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
        aBundleFetch.TblName = Constants.Class;
        Thread objClass = new Thread(FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
        aBundleFetch.TblName = "ClassSubject";
        Thread objClassSubject = new Thread(FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
        aBundleFetch.TblName = "MaterialType";
        Thread objMatType = new Thread(FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));

        objBoard.Start(); objClass.Start(); objClassSubject.Start(); objMatType.Start();
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Please feel free to discuss anything. Sorry for my English and Bad coding.

**EDIT:**

So I have my jsonResult with help of tasks as:-

```
aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Board;
            Func<JsonResult> functionBoard = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
            JsonResult resBoard = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionBoard);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Class;
            Func<JsonResult> functionClass = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
            JsonResult resClass = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClass);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassSubject;
            Func<JsonResult> functionClassSubject = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
            JsonResult resClassSubject = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClassSubject);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassMaterial;
            Func<JsonResult> functionClassMaterial = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
            JsonResult resClassMaterial = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClassMaterial);
```

Now I want to Add them into a single JsonResult and pass it to my js file to use it. Any idea how this will be done?

This gives me error:-

```
JsonResult resultFinal = resBoard.Data  + resClass.Data + resClassSubject.Data + resClassMaterial.Data;
```

Comment: Are you trying to return all lists, or just a specific one depending on the request?

Comment: Depending on request

Comment: Can you explain more why you need this to be done using multi threading? If you only need to return one list then I don't see the need. If you want to merge the results from all the threads and return one list then it make sense, and in that case it will be easier for you to use Tasks and Tasks.WaitAll. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx, also read this full tutorial and it should help you a lot http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: Well, what I need to do is return multiple list and combine them into one. Also, I want to perform list fetching parallel so that it will not take much time.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC its particularly easy to write asynchronous controller methods
Using `async` and `Task`.(Please read the [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123125/asp-net-mvc-multi-threading-is-it-worth-it))

**Example:**

```
public async Task<JsonResult> FetchTblData(AdminBundle abundleList)
{
    AdminBundle abundle = new AdminBundle();
    string innerMesage = string.Empty;
    if (Session["AdminBundle"] != null)
        abundle = (AdminBundle)Session["AdminBundle"];

    //abundle.ListType = Request.Form["TblList"].ToString();
    abundle.ListType = abundleList.ListType;

    if (abundleList.ListType != string.Empty)
    {
        using (SMContext db = new SMContext())
        {
            switch (abundleList.ListType)
            {
                case "Category":                 
                   var CategoryList =await db.CatObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToListAsync();
                    return Json { Data = CategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                //Class Starts
                case "Board":
                   var BoardList =await db.BoardObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToListAsync();
                    return Json { Data = BoardList,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
               default:
                    return Json { Data = innerMesage,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                    //Main default Ends
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json { Data = innerMesage,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I'm getting error :- cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult>' to 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'. on line Thread objBoard = new Thread(FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));

Comment: @Deepak I think when you use `Task` you do not need to run `Thread` manually.

Comment: Ok. I'll go through the example first. Then will let you know.

Comment: @Deepak . one suggestion At first please spend 10 min for reading any article about `async`  and `Task` in ASP.NET MVC.